# Force Python2 with spark-submit

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit

I am creating a Spark application with AWS EMR but spark-submit runs with Python 3 instead of Python 2.
But when I run pyspark instead, it is Python 2.

How can I force spark-submit to use Python 2?

I tried to do

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2
```

but it didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I had this in my code

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

and when I was running print 'hello world' it was crashing because it's not the default print function. But I thought it was crashing because it was using Python 3 instead of Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to insert the

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2
```

statement into the spark-env.sh file?

Comment: Do you mean I should do :

    export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2 

before running the script? 

I tried to SSH to the cluster and run manually spark-submit code.py and it seems to run with Python 2. But when I do it with --steps spark-submit ...  it runs Python 3.

Comment: Hi, I mean whether you have added the PYSPARK_PYTHON environment variable into the $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh file at your cluster nodes. The $SPARK_HOME is the directory where you installed Spark.

Comment: I just tried that and it still doesn't work.
So basically when I call spark-submit from SSH it runs with Python2 but when I add a step 'spark-submit' with AWS console (or cli) it runs Python3.

Comment: actually when I run print(sys.version_info) via spark-submit (adding a step with AWS console) it says that it is Python 2.6.9, but there is "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" if I try to run  'print "hello world"'